# overflow:scroll; in <td>

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, css-tables

Why does the CSS property `overflow:scroll;` not work in `<td>`, while `overflow:hidden;` works well?

```
<table border="1" style="table-layout:fixed; width:100px">
  <tr>
    <td style="overflow:scroll; width:50px;">10000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From the CSS specs<sup>[1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow),[2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout)</sup>, I can't see why.

Comment: Surprisingly, the best answer (IMHO), is the last one. Apply a height to the TD element, and then float it left. This allows for vertical scrolling without adding additional elements to your code as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got something [from here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2006Mar/0030.html#replies)!

> Andrew Fedoniouk wrote:
>
> > This is actually my question:
> >     "One technical reason is that the overflow property does not apply to
> >     tables." - why? What is this reason?
>
> I'm no expert, but I believe this is
>   just for backward compatibility  with
>   legacy table behavior.  You can check
>   the "automatic" table  layout
>   algorithm in the spec.  I'm pretty
>   sure that this layout  algorithm is
>   incompatible with the overflow
>   property (or, more  accurately, the
>   layout algorithm will never result in
>   the need for  any value of overflow
>   except 'visible').
>
> > Yep, this is why I am asking. Seems like there are no formal reasons
> >     why  or  should not be scrollable but seems like
> >     UA vendors reached some silent agreement in this area. So is the
> >     question.
>
> The spec agrees with you with respect
>   to  elements.  Table cells  are
>   supposed to respect overflow, although
>   Mozilla, at least, appears  not to do
>   so.  I can't answer your question in
>   this instance,  although I would still
>   guess the answer is still tied to
>   legacy rendering.

The [main thread is here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2006Mar/0024.html).

Comment: Well, it could if you give it a fixed-layout or a width and no-wrap and so on... However, wrapping it into a div works afaik great in every browser, even in IE6.

Comment: Thanks Kirtan, your info is appreciable. So it is an implementation limit, not a spec problem, and I didn't misread or misunderstand. However, what a shame that there is no further discussion about that thread, and it seems to me that this problem would not be fixed on any browser soon. Besides, I delay to accept this answer in the hope of more fresh info about this problem, because I know you StackOverflower are experts of overflow:)

Comment: Be sure to check out the solution at the very bottom (i.e. set a height and float the td element left). This worked beautifully for me without having to add any additional div elements.

Answer (score 31):

You have to wrap it in a div, that will work:

```
<table border="1" style="table-layout:fixed; width:500px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;"><div style="overflow:scroll; width:100%">10000000000000000000000000000000000</div></td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know a <div> wrapper will work, but don't you think what you answered is not what I asked?

Comment: yes, you are right... I was a little to fast. However, this might be useful for anyone who is looking for a workaround, not the reason.

Comment: the workaround only works for overflow x, however. you cant do div height = 100%....

Comment: @Shawn: I don't get it, what do you mean? You want some workaround for a td with a height of 100%?

Comment: yea, so if the table say is 500px tall and you want the td to take up as much height as possible

Comment: @ATOzTOA: Did you gave it a try?

Comment: This is the answer for anyone who wants a scrollable <td> element in their table.

Comment: Per the answer below, apply a height to the TD element and then float it left. This provides for vertical scrolling without having to add additional elements to your code. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Well this doesn't work, but then it has been over ten years.

Answer (score 14):

Firstly provide desired height to td and then Apply "float: left" property to respective "td" you want scrollbar to appear.

Comment: I was very surprised to see this work, but it provides the EXACT behavior I was looking for. This should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<table border="1" style="table-layout:fixed; width:500px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;"><div style="overflow:scroll; width:100%">10000000000000000000000000000000000</div></td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```