# How to force divs to appear in 1 line with a scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a page here http://arin.esy.es/arin/site/species.php

The problem is that fish divs (which have class "node") appear to wrap in the parent div (with class "row"). I want it so that all the node divs are in 1 line going horizontally in the row div. I don't want it to wrap. In addition there could be more row divs.

I also want it so that none of the row divs get any scroll bars. There should be a horizontal scroll bar but it should be only for the parent of the row div, which is a td tag. Vertical scroll bars should not exist. And the horizontal scroll should only be visible when needed.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table id="fish_container">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="category_container" valign="top">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                            <div class="node" style="background-image: url(http://arin.esy.es/arin/scripts/config/../../pics/category/1/1.png);"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td id="species_container" valign="top"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    background-color:blue;
}

#fish_container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#category_container {
    width:75%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
#species_container {
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.row {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.node {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display: inline-block;  
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.node:hover {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Comment: This should just be CSS, you shouldn't need any Javascript for it.

Comment: can make an element 50000px wide so children don't wrap ( or whatever is reasonable). Set overflow of it's parent to auto or scroll

Comment: I fixed the wrapping by putting css 'nowrap' on row (i updated the css above). But now the problem is the horizontal scroll doesn't show on the td tag.

Comment: Ok the horizontal scroll shows, but the problem is the original layout isn't working. `category_container` needed 75% width, and `species_container` needed 25% width. But `species_container` doesn't even show anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow: scroll` property does not work with tables `<td>`. See this answer:

[overflow:scroll; in <td>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211309/overflowscroll-in-td)

`overflow: hidden` seems to work well with tables, however only if you set the style of `<td>` to `table-layout:fixed`. However `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` will not work under any circumstance.

One way most people work around this is by wrapping the contents between `<td> ... </td>` in a `div`, and then setting the `overflow` property for that `div`.

In your case, that would mean giving the `overflow` style property to the div with `.row` class, since `.row` already surrounds all the contents of the table row:

```
.row {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

I understand this is not what you want, unfortunately what you want is not possible in CSS. Surrounding your table row contents in a `div` is perhaps your best option.