# How to make td overflow go into multiple lines?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, overflow

I need to make the td overflow go into multiple lines as textarea.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td style="max-width:200px;overflow-y:scroll;">Smithasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/huewy6r8/1/)

Comment: put <br/> tag for next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping of text works when whitespaces are found in the text, the text you have written in the `td` above doesn't have any whitespaces, please add whitespaces and then it will start flowing on multiple lines.

Comment: how to hide the bottom scroll ?

Comment: @Raviteja You can add `overflow-x: hidden;` for that. Please check the updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/huewy6r8/2/

Comment: height is increasing if the text overflows [here](https://jsfiddle.net/huewy6r8/3/) scroll should appear

Comment: isn't that what you require for your `td`? To flow text on multiple lines like `textarea`

Comment: for textarea a vertical scroll appears right ? If the text overflows

Comment: I got you, You will need to wrap the `td` contents in a `div` and add `overflow-y:scroll;` to that `div`, check the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/huewy6r8/5/ you can see more details about why you need to do so, check this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211309/overflowscroll-in-td

Comment: width is altered.Not got set to 200px.Inspect the element.

Comment: yup, you are right, please change `max-width` to `width` and it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

That is due to your text. There is no whitspace in your text. just add some white space in your text You can check the fiddler [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zy47ppLj/)

```
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td style="max-width:200px;overflow-y:scroll;">
        Smithasdfas
        dfasdfasdfasdfa sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd 
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf 
</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```