# Add horizontal scrollbar in table cell within container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a `<div class="container">` with `<table class="table">` inside, which looks good. Until the cells become to wide, then the table expands to the full size of the contents.

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Caption</td>
            <td>Some very long string that makes the contents to overflow, actually mich like this actual example in StackOverflow.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I would like to have a horizontal scrollbar when contents are wider then the container (actually like StackOverflow does...).

How do I do that? Add `style="overflow-x: scroll"` on the `<td>` doesn't do anything.

Comment: overflow property can't be applied to table.. see this post for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211309/overflowscroll-in-td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give the `.container` a `max-width`.
2. Then apply the `overflow` style rule to `.container`.

**Example:**

```
.container {
max-width: 400px;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: I don't really want to touch the defaults Bootstrap gives me.