# html table height attribute does not limit height in firefox

Tags: html, css

How can I limit the height of a table in a way that I can scroll the non-visible elements.

It does not seem to work as expected:

http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBZUOCG0C4C8

```
table.ex1 {
    table-layout: auto;
    height: 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

table.ex2 {
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 20px;
      overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

Comment: why not use a wrapper element for it?

Comment: I would prefer a css-only solution

Comment: Doesn't max-height work here?

Comment: did you try using it in other browsers"?

Comment: no max-height working, no other browser working

Comment: then i think tables do not support this css `overflow-y : scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem with the display-type.

If you change the table with `display: block;`, you have your height limit.

This css works on your table (notice that you has not a tbody tag)

```
table {
    display: block;
} 

table tbody {
    display: table;
}
```

EDIT: its a dirty hack, use better a div wrapper and set the overflow property on that element

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:scroll` doesn't work on tables for the following ([taken from this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1211437/4537297)):

> Andrew Fedoniouk wrote:
>
> > *This is actually my question: "One technical reason is that the
> >     overflow property does not apply to tables." - why? What is this
> >     reason?*
>
> I'm no expert, but I believe this is just for backward
>   compatibility with legacy table behavior. You can check the
>   "automatic" table layout algorithm in the spec. I'm pretty sure that
>   this layout algorithm is incompatible with the overflow property (or,
>   more accurately, the layout algorithm will never result in the need
>   for any value of overflow except 'visible').
>
> > *Yep, this is why I am asking. Seems like there are no formal reasons
> >     why or should not be scrollable but seems like UA vendors reached some
> >     silent agreement in this area. So is the question.*
>
> The spec agrees
>   with you with respect to elements. Table cells are supposed to respect
>   overflow, although Mozilla, at least, appears not to do so. I can't
>   answer your question in this instance, although I would still guess
>   the answer is still tied to legacy rendering.

[Original question here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2006Mar/0030.html#replies)

[Main thread here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2006Mar/0024.html)

So, considering that, if you still wish to generate the scrolling behavior, one of the most common alternatives is to wrap the content on a `div` inside the `td`:

```html
<table border="1" style="table-layout:fixed; width:500px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px; height:20px;">
      <div style="overflow: scroll; width:100%; height:100%;">10000000000000000000000000000000000 another</div>
    </td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```