# <tr>/<td> heights being ignored?

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to make a table with a fixed layout: every cell has a predefined height, and if there is extra information inside the cell then there should be a scrollbar. It's very important that every cell have its height declared ahead of time. Yet, as far as I can see it's totally ignoring my (very emphatic) directions on the heights of the rows and cells. It keeps adding extra space to the `<tr>` and `<td>`, to make sure that it can display the entire contents. How do I make it stop?

```html
<table border="1" style="table-layout:fixed; height:400px; width:500px;">
    <tr style="height:50px; min-height:50px; max-height:50px;">
        <td style="height:50px; min-height:50px; max-height:50px; overflow-y:scroll;">
            <div style="height:500px; background-color:#fdc;">abc<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:350px; min-height:350px; max-height:350px;">
        <td style="height:350px; min-height:350px; max-height:350px; overflow-y:scroll;">
            <div style="height:200px; background-color:#cdf;">abc<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is just what tables do, there nothing you can do about it directly. The only thing you can do is put wrapper elements inside your cells, and limit the height of those. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1211410/3744304

Comment: That is bonkers. Yeah, it seems to work. I don't understand it at all.